# How to find a ''Outlook Compatible Mail Designer Tool"

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, outlook

I need to design a responsive html newsletter mail by using html ,embedded-css, and javascript and some js libs.

Now, I know outlook client is a nightmare and I have to use `<table>` instead of `<div>` and `<b>` instead of `<strong>`, etc. for the sake of responsive design, once you replace this then it is not compatible for gmail or yahoo or mobile. So I realised that I can use outlook-specific css code-snippets, and according to [MailChimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/), It looks like below:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Your Outlook-specific CSS goes here. */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

I can't track all the html elements for all the devices, so I've looked for a html mail designer tool for free, but no luck. What kind a path should I follow on this? I just want this nonsense be automated by such a tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you shouldn't use Javascript in your email. Webmail clients are mostly running the interface in JavaScript and are not keen on your email interfering with that, and desktop client filters often consider JavaScript to be an indicator of spam or phishing emails.

Even in the cases where it might run, there really is little benefit to scripting in emails. Keep your emails as straight HTML and CSS, and avoid the hassle.

In terms of developing for Outlook theres no need to track all the elements for all devices. Take a fluid approach to building your email and it will degrade gracefully across email clients, yes even Outlook.

Start here with this article: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919

Use the email template they provided [here](https://github.com/tutsplus/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries) as a starter template and add your own custom styles. **Place all the styles in the head** and inline your template before sending it.

Essentially the template works in all major clients. It works in Outlook as well by wrapping the body in conditional tags:

```
 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <table width="600" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#4d4d4d;" >
  <tr>
  <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
  <![endif]-->

[HTML EMAIL BODY GOES HERE]

 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->
```

And by wrapping the two, three, and four column rows in conditional tags as well.

For [Outlook specific things](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/396-conditional-code-for-outlook) use conditional tags to target different versions of Outlook. From the link above:

Target all versions of Outlook with this:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
[HTML code]
<![endif]-->
```

And I use the same for my conditional CSS

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style></style>
<![endif]-->
```

And sometimes include separate conditional CSS to only target 2007+

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style></style>
<![endif]-->
```

Also, I have found with conditional CSS that is really matters that the !important is there and that is has a space before it. It looks like you already have that correct, although one of your rules background: blue; did not have !important.

So, for example...

```
li {padding-left: 2px!important;}
```

Will not work, instead you need to write:

```
li {padding-left: 2px !important;}
```

Check the code being output carefully.. some ESPs also add the !important even if you already have it, so you might also being ending up with !important !important which will mean they won't work.

But again theres no need to track every element when taking the fluid approach. You won't have that many styles within the Outlook conditional tags. Most likely you'll only have something like this:

```
 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And the other HTML within conditional tags that I mentioned above. Take a good look the template I linked above. You can move the layout around by copy and pasting the table rows to customize it to suit your needs.

I code HTML emails everyday in my day job so please reach out if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Thanks @Mia. You explained very well. Actually, I was just removing script codes I dont need. Looks like Im going to deal with these 'mso's a while. I am following the fluid design tuts you refered now. If I can handle this, I will start trying to solve spam issues.

Comment: can you tell me how you test your email for all outlook clients from 'mso 9' to 'mso 15'? setting up a vm and over on it? or using a paid-service like litmus preview the design for end-user's view?

Comment: I use Litmus: https://litmus.com/ and Return Path: https://returnpath.com/ to test all my emails. I prefer Litmus as you can build the email directly in Litmus and the email previews are generated a lot faster than Return Path.

Comment: I see you deleted your previous message but I looked at your code and it looks like you didn't inline your styles. Also the conditional tags your using should start with this:  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> not if mso.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I just thought that it would be absurd to you look at the codes. But thanks again anyway. I tested either way for mso versions, it resulted the same. Somehow those condional css codes didnt work, that actually confused me. But in whole this, something always goes wrong. So yesterday I found the mailchimp design from scratch feature, I tested in outlook 2013 and it is working perfectly even responsible. But first, I m gonna reorder all css into inline form right away. I realised that mail developing is another world.